# How to prove derivative of logarithm with base $b$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I learned how to derive a logarithm with any base. This is the formula:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log_bx=\frac{1}{x\ln b}$$

How can it be proved?

Comment: From the identity $\log_b x = \frac{\log x}{\log b}$ and the special case $\frac{d}{dx} \log x = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: $\log_b a = \frac{\log_x b}{\log_x c} \log_c a$ hence all the logarithms are the same off a multiplicative constant, and $ f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$ is a logarithm since $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the definition of $\log_b x =\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln b}$.