# When differentiating the logarithm, log(x), to get 1/x, does the choice of base matter?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

We know that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = 1/x $$

where the base is understood to be Euler's number, e, but does this algorithm still hold true if we change the base to, say, 2 or 3 or 10?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764619/how-to-prove-derivative-of-logarithm-with-base-b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that, by the change-of-base formula,
$$\log_a(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$$
so the derivative isn't exactly the same as that of the natural log, but it is within a constant factor:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log_a(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln(a)}$$

Comment: Very nice reminder of the change-of-base formula -- thanks so much ...

Comment: @D.Hutchinson No problem! If you found it helpful, don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark}!$ :D

Comment: ok, done and done :)